# "I move it away from me" vs. "I move it away from myself"

Tags: word-usage

To practice my English, I am trying to explain the word "push" in English

> If I push an apple, I move the apple forward and **away from myself**.

I guess it's a little bit strange to say

> ... and **away from me**.

Because the subject of the sentence and the object of "from" are the same person.

With the agreement above, [the explanation/definition of "push" on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/push) seems to be a little bit strange

> to use physical pressure or force, especially with your hands, in order to move something into a different position, usually one that is farther away **from you**

Should "yourself" be used there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cambridge Dictionary is correct! You move something away from you.

In your example you mention "the object of *from*". But the verb here is *move*. The subject is *I* and the object is *the apple*. So the subject and the object are not the same person. (They are not even the same species!)

We say,

> *I pushed the apple away from me*
>
> *He pushed it away from him*
>
> *We pushed them away from us*
>
> etc.

And we say,

- *He has hurt himself*

where the subject and the *direct* object are the same person

and

- *She talks to herself*
  and
- *I sent myself a letter*

where the subject and the *indirect* object are the same person.

It is difficult. The rules have exceptions. It might be useful to collect examples of the usage of reflexive pronouns. I think we use "me" much more often than "myself", if that helps!

Comment: Thank you. For the first example, you would say "I move the apple forward and away from **me**", right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why you are describing it so precisely, but yes! We would normally just say, *I move the apple away from me* or *I move the apple forward.* If you move it forward it MUST be away from you!!